# Redefining function from standard library

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang

Context: In a recent conversation, the question "does gcc/clang do `strlen("static string")` at compile time?" came up. After some testing, the answer seems to be yes, regardless the level of optimization. I was a bit surprised to see this done even at `-O0`, so I did some testing, and eventually arrived to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long strlen(const char* s) {
  return 10;
}

unsigned long f() {
  return strlen("abcd");
}

unsigned long g(const char* s) {
  return strlen(s);
}

int main() {
  printf("%ld %ld\n",f(),g("abcd"));
  return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, it prints `4 10` and not `10 10`. I tried compiling with `gcc` and `clang`, and with various flags (`-pedantic`, `-O0`, `-O3`, `-std=c89`, `-std=c11`, ...) and the behavior is consistent between the tests.

Since I didn't include `string.h`, I expected my definition of `strlen` to be used. But the assembly code shows indeed that `strlen("abcd")` was basically replaced by `return 4` (which is what I'm observing when running the program).

Also, the compilers print no warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` (more precisely, none related to the issue: they still warn that parameter `s` is unused in my definition of `strlen`).

Two (related) questions arise (I think they are related enough to be asked in the same question):
 - is it allowed to redefine a standard function in C when the header declaring it isn't included?
 - does this program behave as it should? If so, what happens exactly?

Comment: If you compile above code with `gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` it gives error like _function declaration isn’t a prototype_ So that makes clear I think about the point you mentioned _is it allowed to redefine a standard function in C when the header declaring it isn't included?_

Comment: @achal Oh, I didn't know about `-Wstrict-prototypes`, thanks, I learned something. However, if I use `void` as parameter for `f` and `main` to remove those warnings, the behavior of the program doesn't change (it still prints `4 10`), so I'm not sure I understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: I guess `strlen("abcd")` is _obviously_ a constant the compiler has replaced by the value 4 because it recognize `strlen()`. IOTH `g("abcd")` is not _obviously_ constant so the compiler emits code that calls your `strlen()` function (but try to declare g() and strlen() as static inline).

Comment: Re-using the standard library function names for sinister purposes invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per C 2011 (draft N1570) 7.1.3 1 and 2:

> All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses … are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.
>
> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

The “following subclauses” specify the standard C library, including `strlen`. Your program defines `strlen`, so its behavior is undefined.

What is happening in the case you observe is:

- The compiler knows how `strlen` is supposed to behave, regardless of your definition, so, while optimizing `strlen("abcd")` in `f`, it evaluates `strlen` at compile time, resulting in four.
- In `g("abcd")`, the compiler fails to recognize that, because of the definition of `g`, this is equivalent to `strlen("abcd")`, so it does not optimize it at compile time. Instead, it compiles it to a call to `g`, and it compiles `g` to call `strlen`, and it also compiles your definition of `strlen`, with the result that `g("abcd")` calls `g`, which calls your `strlen`, which returns ten.

The C standard would allow the compiler to discard your definition of `strlen` completely, so that `g` returned four. However, a good compiler should warn that your program defines a reserved identifier.

Comment: Is there any way replacing `strlen("abcd");` with `4` removes the required sequence point resulting from the function call in the source code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The compiler is responsible for ensuring the semantics remain correct when it optimizes. In this case, the sequence point specified by 6.5.2.2 10 is only guaranteed to be between (a) the evaluation of the function designator and the arguments and (b) the actual call. None of those have side effects here, so the sequence point is irrelevant. Whether the arguments and the function call are sequence relative to other things is not controlled by that sequence point.