# clang-analyze: how to avoid "garbage value" warning?

Tags: c, fread, garbage, clang-static-analyzer, false-positive

When checking

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    c[20];
    size_t  l;

    l = fread(c, sizeof c, 1, stdin);
    if (l != 1)
        return 1;

    return c[0] == 42;
}
```

with clang, I get

```
$ clang  --analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=alpha x.c
x.c:13:14: warning: The left operand of '==' is a garbage value
        return c[0] == 42;
               ~~~~ ^

$ clang -v
clang version 7.0.1 (Fedora 7.0.1-4.fc29)
```

Is there really a chance that `c` contains garbage at this point?  If not, how can I avoid the warning (without the obvious initialization of `c`)?

### Update

Because it seems to be common consensus, that this is a false positive, I want to focus on the way how to avoid the warning.

It is true that `fread()` is a standard function and analyzers should know their semantics as they are doing e.g. for `memset()` already.  But I am interested in a more generic way which can be used e.g. on library functions.

I would call some special function (let call it `assert_defined()`) in a way like

```
    l = fread(c, sizeof c, 1, stdin);
    assert_defined(c, l * sizeof c);
```

which is

- a noop
- but lets the compiler/analyzer think that `l * sizeof c` bytes at `c` are initialized

Does clang know annotations like

```
inline static void assert_defined(void const *p, size_t cnt) 
   __attribute__((__dear_compiler_this_memory_is_not_garbage__(1,2)))
{
}
```

or are there tricks like the related

```
int i = i;
```

which prevents gcc to emit "uninitialized warnings"?

Comment: @Eugene read last statement?

Comment: @machine_1 read and removed. Weird that the tool is complaining. Anyway, a workaround could be to initialize `c`.

Comment: But looks like your usage of `fread` is incorrect. The second argument should be the size of *one* element.

Comment: `c[0]` can contain garbage if `fread()` failed to read any data. But you already test for that. It might not be smart enough to realize this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `fread(c, sizeof c, 1, stdin);` and `fread(c, 1, sizeof c, stdin);` both attempt to read the same amount of data, but the first will report `0` if it can't read it all.

Comment: @EugeneSh.in this example one element has the size of 20 bytes; in real world, `c` might be some structured data

Comment: @ensc For that case it should take `&c` as the first argument. Yes, for arrays it might not matter, but it is demonstrating the intention. Perhaps it could matter for the analyzer?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Logically it should take `c`, and it would make a difference if `fread` took `char *` rather than `void *`.

Comment: @R.. Logically it should take the pointer to the type of the element whose size is passed as the second argument.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: OK that's a reasonable position.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to avoid using  a single `l` as a symbol name; in many fonts it is not clearly distinguishable from `1`.

Comment: Your update is a new question.  Since this one already had answers that do not address the second question, it would have been better to post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it could contain garbage - if `fread()` fails.

For the analyser to understand that the check guarantees `c[0]` is not read if `fread` fails would require the analyser to understand the semantics of the `fread()` function.  That's computationally expensive task for any non-trivial code, and would require either sight of the library source, or encoding of the standard library semantics - which is possible but would only spot a small subset of issues involving "known functions".

Initialising the array will avoid this specific issue:

```
char c[20] = {0} ;
```

Comment: The case `fread` is failing is covered by the code. The question is why the analyzer can't catch it.

Comment: The question was: "If not, how can I avoid the warning (without the obvious initialization of c)?"

Comment: when `fread()` fails, `l` will be `0` and `c[0]` will never be accessed.  I would like to avoid the explicit initialization to catch cases where `c` is really undefined.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It assumes that the analyser understands the semantics of `fread()`.  Possible but unlikely perhaps for standard library functions but not generally true of any arbitrary function.

Comment: @R..  But does it?  And if it did would it be worth much if it could only do that for a small set of "known" functions - any third-party library would be unknown.

Comment: @ensc : Initialising all variables is generally considered good practice and is required in many coding standards, I also have an opinion about multiple returns in a single function.  You should not perhaps use a static analysis tool as a crutch to support poor coding practices.

Comment: @Clifford dump initialization of variables is a bad practice which hides many programming errors which would be detected by compilers else.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think the analyzer cannot understand that the `if` after the `fread` instruction controls errors. The `fread` function is a standard library function, but who says the code uses the standard library. Instead of `fread` the function could be `gread` ... what's the expected analyzer behaviour in this case?

Comment: @SirJoBlack Analyzers can understand pretty fancy stuff these days. I am pretty sure Coverity would understand it very well (but these are different weight classes, of course). Anyway, this one is a clear false positive.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Coverity is paid for. Perhaps you get what you pay for with static analysis?

Comment: @Clifford That's what I am saying. False positive that's it, but not totally impossible to get rid of.

Comment: @Clifford: Any third-party library can be known because it's (in theory) portable source that the analysis tool can inspect. The standard functions on the other hand may not be written in [portable] C, and from a standpoint of judging correctness, what it's *specified* to do is more important than what your particular implementation does (e.g. even if a function always had some special property on your particular implementation, if it's not part of the specified behavior, assuming it would be a bug in the program).

Comment: @R..  I am not sure of your point or whether you are agreeing, disagreeing or just raising a new point.  Not all libraries are distributed as source code, which was my point.  I don't think we disagree.  It is academic in context of this question and this tool where the evidence is that it does not know the semantics.  The comments were fairly initiated in response to my original incomplete answer, which I have edited.  As it happens the fix is just _better code_ so in that sense a "clever" tool would have passed some pretty hideous code (IMO).

Comment: @Clifford: If you have third-party libraries that aren't distributed as source then you really can't analyze the correctness of the program beyond a limited degree without binary analysis. Perhaps it would be nice to have frameworks for expressing their contracts and analyzing with the assumption that they actually honor their contracts. Anyway what I was saying is that it *does make sense* to treat the standard library (which is part of the language) as special and analyze based on its specified behavior.

Comment: Sight of the library source is not required; the analyzer could assume the function behaves as specified by the C Standard

Comment: @M.M  Yes, I said that.  I think we are all in violent agreement about the possibilities.  I am not justifying the behaviour of clang-analyze, just explaining it - answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the compiler is not supposed to know the working of the function fread(). From the perspective of the compiler, fread() may or may not modify 'c'.

So if you do not explicitly initialize your variable in your specific case, the compiler has no option but to emit a warning.

Comment: A static analyzer is allowed to know all about myriad APIs, especially the standard library, as many as useful to improve accuracy. Likewise, a compiler may know for improved optimisation, though is less likely to, as the benefits are generally marginal.

Comment: `fread` is part of the C language, and most certainly does modify `c[0]` if it doesn't return 0.

Comment: clang-analyze is not a compiler; it is a static analysis tool intended to catch _semantic_ errors that a compiler _syntax_ checker does not.  As such saying what the compiler should or should not do is not the issue or in dispute.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for bringing that to my attention. In this case, the cause could be that the source of fread() is not available for the analyser and as such has no way of telling whether it shall modify the first parameter unless it has the necessary information regarding standard library functions.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Since `fread` is part of the C library, a program [cannot redefine it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741722/redefining-function-from-standard-library).  Both a compiler and an analyzer can and should have built-in knowledge of its behavior, just like an analyzer must know what `malloc` and `free` do in order to report resource leaks.