# What happens if I name a function the same in my code as one that already exists in a library

Tags: c, function

I have a question regarding naming functions in C:

I am trying to implement `malloc` myself however for this I need the library `stdlib.h` which already contains `malloc`. So I was wondering which one of those two functions would be given priority would the function that I have written the used or the one that is in the library?

I know that I could give my function a different name like `mymalloc` but due to several reasons I do not want to give it a different name.

Comment: I can't recall the finer details, but there are allowances made in C for the provision of a user-defined `malloc`.  (You need to tell the linking stage about it too.) There's quite possibly a Q & A page on this site that covers this.

Comment: The C standard leaves undefined what happens if you do this.  Some specific implementations (compiler/library/OS combination) might document how they handle it, so you'll have to tell us what you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redefining function from standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741722/redefining-function-from-standard-library)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `malloc` in applications linked to the C library is tricky: depending on the target system specifics, you might get into difficult to solve problems.

The main issue is you must redefine all allocation functions whose implementation must be consistent:

```
/* 7.22.3 Memory management functions */
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
void free(void *p);
void *malloc(size_t size);
void *realloc(void *p, size_t size);
char *strdup(const char *s);
char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n);
```

And also `malloc_size()` or `malloc_usable_size()` for safety.